# Change Oracle Database Password Password From APEX

Tags: database, oracle, oracle-apex

I am attempting to implement a form on APEX that allows the user (in this case dba's) to select a database and then change their username and password.

I was able to set up the input fields correctly but I am totally lost on how to tie it in with the actual database. I am assuming I will have to use a database link to access different databases.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I devised a solution that does not require stored procedures or elevated access for a single user. Its a bit hacked together but it works!

1. The user inputs their credentials and desired new password through a regular APEX form.
2. The form data gets processed in an HTML region with an iframe in it using substitution strings. i.e:`<iframe height='300' width='100%' scrolling="no" src="http://***SERVER***/cgi-bin/chguserpwd.cgi dbname=&DATABASE_NAME.&username=&USERNAME.&oldpwd=&CURR_PASSWORD.&newpwd=&NEW_PASSWORD."></iframe>`
3. The cgi script does the work and returns the result through the iframe

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/ksh 
   my_input=$QUERY_STRING;
   dbname=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" |awk '{FS="&"} {print $1}'|awk '{FS="="} {print $2}'`
   username=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" |awk '{FS="&"} {print $2}'|awk '{FS="="} {print $2}'`
   oldpwd=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" |awk '{FS="&"} {print $3}'|awk '{FS="="} {print $2}'`
   newpwd=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" |awk '{FS="&"} {print $4}'|awk '{FS="="} {print $2}'`
   print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"; print " Database Name is       $dbname ............ User is $username "; 

   cd **dir**
   ./chguserpwd  $dbname $username $oldpwd  $newpwd
   ```
4. Execute the SQL from the cgi-script `./chguserpwd`

   ```
   set markup HTML on
   prompt .
   alter user &1 identified by &2;
   prompt Password has been changed
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you will be able to do something like this:

```
alter user xyz@remote_database identified by new_password
```

You will probably need to write a stored procedure on the remote database that accepts the username and password and alters that users password for you. Then you can execute:

```
begin
   change_password('xyz','new_password')@remote_database;
end;
```